# Compare pandas dataframes and check overlaps?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, compare

I am trying myself out at spame filters. I tried several methods to label text files as spam. As a result, I have three dataframes. They basically look like this:

```
df_method_1 = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A','B' ,'C'], 'spam': ['1', '0', '0']})
df_method_2 = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A','B' ,'C'], 'spam': ['1', '1', '0']})
df_method_3 = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A','B' ,'C'], 'spam': ['1', '1', '0']})
```

I am now trying to creat a dataframe showing, if a file was labled as spam and if so by which method.

In the best case, I can create a dataframe containing the following infortmation:

```
df_summary = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A','B' ,'C'], 'spam': ['All methods', 'Method 2 & Method 3', 'No method']})
```

Obviously, I am looking for the information. No need for the actual strings.

I tried `pandas.DataFrame.isin()` to make it happen. But I failed. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `merge()`?

```
df1.merge(df2, on="file").merge(df3, on="file")
  file spam_x spam_y spam
0    A      1      1    1
1    B      0      1    1
2    C      0      0    0
```